# `sudo apt-get update` /`sudo apt-get upgrade` returned error for packages

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I was doing `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`; on `apt-get upgrade` it got stuck loading for 45 minutes and when it finished it returned with an error.

This is what I read:

```
Archive:  /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2288178-linux.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2288178-linux.zip or
        /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2288178-linux.zip.zip, and cannot find /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2288178-linux.zip.ZIP, period.
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_4.12.0-ubuntu0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: Does anything change after having run `sudo apt-get clean`?

Comment: @DevRobot Please use four-space indentation to format code blocks, not `<pre></pre>` tags, and in general please avoid using HTML tags if there's a Markdown alternative

Comment: KatyN, please have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for instructions on how to format posts properly

Comment: Is your internet connection stable?

Answer (score 0):

The post-installation script blocks the system and in this case, the solution is simple, the post-removal and pre-removal scripts are ok. Therefore remove the package via

```
sudo apt-get remove android-studio
```

and I would say, also the PPA. There are more reliable methods to install Android Studio.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```

Comment: It appears that [ubuntu-make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) is the official way to get android studio